# Which domains are contractible on $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: general-topology, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $\mathbb{C}^n$ be the complex Euclidean space.
The wiki of contractible tells us that any Euclidean space is contractible, as is any star domain on a Euclidean space.

**My question is:**

1, Is a  Euclidean convex domain in $\mathbb{C}^n$ contractible?  (An Euclidean convex domain seems to be a star domain)

2, Is a  domain of holomorphy (which is weaker than Euclidean convex) in $\mathbb{C}^n$ contractible?

3, Is a simply connected  open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ contractible?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: (1) convex sets are star-like. (3) For $n\geq2$, $\mathbb C^n$ minus one point is simply connected but not contractible.

Comment: (2) is false if $n = 1$, e.g., consider the domain of $1/z$. I don't know about $n > 1$.

Comment: For (2), consider $f(z_1,\ldots,z_n) = \frac{1}{z_1}$.